# Create Django Rest Framework ad-hoc post method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm use Django Rest Framework and I would like to create an ad-hoc post method for registering new users.

When I tried the code bellow I get the following error :

> Expected view UserViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)


    @list_route(methods=['post'])
    def register(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        user.save()
        return Response(user)
```

Comment: As the error states the view set is excepting you to passed the unique primary identity feild for the model in your URL.

Comment: i know and error apear when i call self.get_object() , in my  i need url like /users/register/ for create new users. do you know how i can do it? @GlynJackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a **new** user, therefore there is no object to be gotten with `self.get_object()`. This method would work if you were working on viewing, changing or deleting an object that **already** exists (and would be identified by the `pk` parameter in the URL pattern).

You should just create a new user object rather than call `self.get_object()`.